# Триггер на запрет добавления имеющегося студента

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня имеется база данных с преподавателями, персоналом и студентами. Интересует именно таблица студентов. Столкнулся с такой проблемой что нужно автоматически проверять имеющуюся строку по нескольким полям. То бишь не только сравнивать по фамилии но и по имени, отчеству, месту жительства

[image: a busy cat]

Пробовал реализовать вот так:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr13
ON dbo.People
FOR INSERT
AS
if 0 < ( SELECT COUNT(P.Stud_ID)
        FROM People P, inserted I
        WHERE P.Stud_IMYA=I.Stud_IMYA AND  P.Stud_FAM=I.Stud_FAM 
        )
        BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RAISERROR (‘Данный студент уже зачислен', 16,10)
        END
```

Проблема в том что когда разные фамилии а имена одинаковые, наоборот он жалуется.  То бишь вот в чем вопрос: как реализовать так, чтобы добавляемый пользователь был уникальным если даже фамилии имена совпадают а отчество нет, то по сути это разные люди, а триггер отлавливает его.

Comment: Вы уверены, что хотите именно триггер? Проще всего задать такое ограничение в виде `CONSTRAINT` на уникальность нужных полей. `ALTER TABLE People ADD CONSTRAINT C_STUD_UNIQUE UNIQUE (Stud_IMYA , Stud_FAM);`

Comment: Да нужен триггер именно. Но видите уникальность полей не работает если Пак Владислав есть, то 2 Пак владислав который жживет в другом городе не пройдет( Я не понимаю как прописать проверку на уникальность всей строки даже если все поля кроме одного одинаковые.

Comment: Если пары _(Фамилия, Имя)_ недостаточно для однозначной идентификации человека - так и добавьте все остальные нужные признаки в уникальный ключ (или индекс), допустим _(Фамилия, Имя, Отчество, ДатаРождения, Адрес)_. Если вот это всё не влезает в максимально допустимую длину ключа (900 байт), тогда уж триггер сочинять.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr1
ON PEOPLE
FOR INSERT, update
AS
IF 2 = (SELECT COUNT(P.Stud_ID)
        FROM People P, INSERTED I
        WHERE P.Stud_FAM like I.Stud_FAM
        AND P.Stud_IMYA like I.Stud_IMYA)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRAN
            raiserror ('Студент уже зачислен', 16, 10)
        END
```

До меня дошло) проверку немного по другому делать надо было.

Comment: Вы можете гарантировать, что в таблице INSERTED всегда будет одна-единственная запись? В противном случае желаемого результата данный триггер может и не достичь.